# How to send a byte array as json using Visual Basic 6?

Tags: json, vb6

I have an Visual Basic 6 application which should read a file into a byte array, put that into a json object and make a post request to a rest API. I have everything working except the byte array part. When I use the code below, the API just receives the string "bytes" and not the actual content of the request that should look something like this "`JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKCj`"

```
Private Function PostDocumentPrint() As String
        'Create http client
        Dim http As Object
        Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")
        url = "XXX"
        http.Open "Post", url, False
        
        'Set request parameters
        http.SetRequestHeader "charset", "UTF-8"
        http.SetTimeouts 500, 500, 500, 500
     
        
        ' Read file into byte array
        Dim fileNum As Integer
        Dim bytes() As Byte
        fileNum = FreeFile
        Open "FileToSend.pdf" For Binary As fileNum
        ReDim bytes(LOF(fileNum) - 1)
        Get fileNum, , bytes
        Close fileNum

        ' Send the request
        Dim jsonStringPostBody As String
        jsonStringPostBody = " {""fileData"": "" " + bytes + """} "   
        http.Send jsonStringPostBody
End Function
```

I believe I need to convert the byte array to a string somehow. For example I tried this:

```
Dim s As String
s = StrConv(bytes, vbUnicode)
MsgBox s
```

But it does not look correct.

Comment: Your `fileData` looks like it's base64 encoded. Google it.